# Need a circuit to find Pulsers per revolution for a rotory Encoder

Tags: microcontroller, operational-amplifier, digital-logic, pic

Need to find Pulses per revolution for a Renco rotary encoder P/N 77822-224 (No longer manufacture by Renco).

- Supply voltage: 5.0v
- Current: 70ma
- Code: Incremental and once around Pulse Marker
- Output format:     Logic Levels: Logic "1" 2.5 Vdc min.  Logic "0"
  .5Vdc  max.
- Output type: LM2901 (Quad Comparator).

I have tried using a PIC micro to count the # of pulse for one revolution by using a stepper motor and the once around Pulse Marker (using the interrupt pin for the pic. micro).
But the pulse count is different each time. Is there a circuit than I can use to clean up the pulse single, or maybe some one has a DIY circuit that they could share to accomplish this task in counting revolutions for this type of Encoder?

Comment: Optical quadrature encoder? About how many pulses are you expecting and how fast are you turning the shaft?

Comment: schematic would help too...

Comment: ANd a scope trace that shows the once per round vs the encoder pulses.

Comment: @Trevor_G you need a schematic of a simple pic. micro hook up to a encoder that has a LM2901 built into it.

Comment: @AmosDeCarmo what does the signal measure on a DMM with rotation? 0~5V with 1K or what?  This is a pretty trivial measurement

Comment: What no test equipment? scope? DMM? counter?    I would expect up to 10k pulse per index pulse, and you forgot to say what your results were

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany yes it is a Optical quadrature encoder. RPM 1,  expecting 1250 to 2000 pulses. But getting pulse counts from 900 to 2200. I know for a fact that 2200 is out of the ball park.

Comment: I'm confused by the question.... You are counting once arounds(indexes) or steps per index? Are you qualifying the edge with the other edge?

Comment: re schematics. DOes the encoder need pull-ups....

Comment: You should be able to do it with a PIC, even one without a QEI peripheral, if you turn the shaft smoothly and slowly. The fact you are getting flaky counts suggests a firmware issue.

Comment: @Tony Stewart NO scope, NO counter yes to DMM. With no scope or counter that is why I B.B. a pic. micro with a LCD display circuit and program it to do the counting. These a surplus encoders that were given to a robot club (F.I.R.S.T) to see if they can use it in there robot.

Comment: @Trevor_G tried without and with pull-ups

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Pefhany That is the same thing I was thinking (firmware issue) but I am not sure.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75  Logic Levels: Logic "1" 2.5 Vdc min. Logic "0" .5Vdc max.

Comment: ARe you turning it smoothly with a stepper or stepping it around?

Comment: @Trevor_G  turning it smoothly with the stepper.

Comment: Got a binary counter IC and measure from index Start to index stop then read binary outputs or put 2mA LED's on them maybe your routine is too slow.

Comment: "I have tried using a PIC micro" - show us your code. "tried without and with pull-ups' - what value pullups, and what voltages did you read with and without pullups when rotating the shaft?